# jQuery how to keep selected option for dynamically created list on page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Got a select list that populates using javascript, each time the page reloads the list is reset. and the selection selected by the user is lost, however for all other input options such as radio button, checkboxes or text fields no data is lost.

```
//example of dynamcially generated options for a dropdown list
<p id="question">How old are you (in years)?</p>
<select id="q1" name="age" style="width:157px;"></select>
<script language="Javascript"> initializeAgeList("Select Your Age",100); </script> 

//example of static options for a radio button set
<p id="question">Are you male or female?</p>
<input type = 'radio' name ='q3' value= 'male' required>Male<BR>
<input type = 'radio' name ='q3' value= 'female'>Female
```

Tried using a global var to determine if the list was already set, but that proved not to work

```
 var isAgeSet = false; //global var

 function initializeAgeList(default_selection,limit ){
     if(!isAgeSet){ //checks to see if list has already been set, on page refresh is set to zero
         var i = 0;
         while (i <= limit){ //adds options until limit is reached
              if(i==0){
                  $("#q1").append(new Option(default_selection,i));
              }else{
                  $("#q1").append(new Option(i,i));
              }
              i++;
          }
          isAgeSet = true;
      }
 };
```

How can I prevent the loss of the user's selected option in a dropdownlist using jQuery?

Comment: Could you please repeat that, your browser remembers the choices made in radios and other inputs when you refresh the page ?

Comment: On top of what @adeneo said, show us some more html e.g (radio buttons etc). If you refresh the page those other options should be lost as well, unless of course you're setting them with server side code and you've got an issue with that?If so show us that as well

Comment: all other elements are statically created options on the html page, the radio button group has three options yes no maybe. so on a page refresh the option last selected in recalled correctly. Dynamically created options for a select list however are not being recollected and I am wondering how can I do so in the event that the page is refreshed.

Comment: That is **not** normal behaviour, HTML is stateless and does not remember the choices a user makes across several page loads.

Comment: Use cookies and that might solve one of your problems. By the way, be careful when creating new objects inside a loops.

Comment: have to save the state somewhere, cookies, localStorage or update server and store there are the choices....then pull state from chosen storage and set elements

Comment: @TommyBs I have added an example of a radio button group. Simple as it may be, but if I select a value and press F5 the value i selected remains the same, but for the dropdown list the value is lost.

Comment: @charlietfl could you please point me to some more information regarding this topic?

Comment: You're getting the radio selected because of cache. Caching a static element can be achieved by the browser but remember that your drop down is dynamic. Try to hit CTRL + F5 (presuming you're using windows) and see if the state still is the same as your selection.

Comment: What marvelous browser caches the state of a radio button, I want one of those !

Comment: @Mario yes I am using windows. I just attempted the CTRL +F5 and the option was not cached, for my selected option was rest.

Comment: @adeneo i never said anything about several page loads. I have one single page with questions. I just want to maintain the state of the answers if the page is reloaded. All other objects on the page appear correctly minus the dynamically created select list.

Comment: Regarding storing state please take a few minutes to read this and you'll probably find the correct way to implement a good state storage for your forms. https://www.inkling.com/read/javascript-definitive-guide-david-flanagan-6th/chapter-20/localstorage-and-sessionstorage

Comment: @user2672744 - you really can't without storing the state somewhere, like in cookies, localStorage or on the serverside, those are the three ways to store data, and you have to use one of them, as your browser surely doesn't remember the state of your form.

Comment: @Mario thank you for the information. I just did a second check and noted that all my previously selected values were also reset.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to persist your data between page postbacks. 
You should save your selected data and read it when page loads (if there is saved data).
The data can be saved to a server (database / file) or on the client (local storage).

Hope this is what you needed...

Yaniv

Comment: Close, I am in mid process and the user has hit the refresh button so I just want the value to reappear as previously selected. Once I get to the submission process well i'm at a crossroad and at this time I'm informed there is no turning back.

This all happened cause I was requested to change the textbox to a dropdownlist, and since I choose to dynamcially create the listbox instead of using hardcoded options I encountered this issue and it annoys me while I'm testing so I thought there must be a way around this to save me time :)

Comment: You can get the selected value with the "onchange" event and save it to localstorage. You than read it on page load and select this option. You should also erase this value on page submit.

Comment: Thanks I have been reading up on this localstorage and it's what I need to implement. :)